# How to list all users in a Linux group?

Tags: linux, unix

How do I list all members of a group in Linux (and possibly other unices)?

Comment: @Silmari89, Not if he wants to do it programmatically.

Comment: I'm new here, I found out that SF exists right after I posted the question. I agree it belongs either to SF or SO.

Comment: Heh, of course, now it has a programmatic solution, so it could be justified here as well.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no good, portable way to do this that I know of.  If you attempt to parse /etc/group, as others are suggesting, you will miss users who have that group as their primary group and anyone who has been added to that group via a mechanism other than UNIX flat files (i.e. LDAP, NIS, pam-pgsql, etc.).

If I absolutely had to do this myself, I'd probably do it in reverse: use `id` to get the groups of every user on the system (which will pull all sources visible to NSS), and use Perl or something similar to maintain a hash table for each group discovered noting the membership of that user.

Edit: Of course, this leaves you with a similar problem: how to get a list of every user on the system.  Since my location uses only flat files and LDAP, I can just get a list from both locations, but that may or may not be true for your environment.

Edit 2: Someone in passing reminded me that `getent passwd` will return a list of all users on the system including ones from LDAP/NIS/etc., *but* `getent group` still will still miss users that are members only via the default group entry, so that inspired me to write this quick hack.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
#
# Lists members of all groups, or optionally just the group
# specified on the command line
#
# Copyright © 2010-2013 by Zed Pobre (zed@debian.org or zed@resonant.org)
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
# purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
# copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
#

use strict; use warnings;

$ENV{"PATH"} = "/usr/bin:/bin";

my $wantedgroup = shift;

my %groupmembers;
my $usertext = `getent passwd`;

my @users = $usertext =~ /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+):/gm;

foreach my $userid (@users)
{
    my $usergrouptext = `id -Gn $userid`;
    my @grouplist = split(' ',$usergrouptext);

    foreach my $group (@grouplist)
    {
        $groupmembers{$group}->{$userid} = 1;
    }
}

if($wantedgroup)
{
    print_group_members($wantedgroup);
}
else
{
    foreach my $group (sort keys %groupmembers)
    {
        print "Group ",$group," has the following members:\n";
        print_group_members($group);
        print "\n";
    }
}

sub print_group_members
{
    my ($group) = @_;
    return unless $group;

    foreach my $member (sort keys %{$groupmembers{$group}})
    {
        print $member,"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all who answered.

I was looking for a portable way to do it. Your information that there's not an easy and portable way was helpful. You also detailed the most on the circumstances which helped me understand the problem more deeply, I appreciate that and I chose your answer as the accepted one.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to donate your script to the Linux foundation? It is 2012 and there are still no easy way to get the members of a group. That is the thing that frustrate me about Linux.

Comment: I added an ISC-like license for you, which should be compatible with just about any group.  Feel free to submit it anywhere you think it will be accepted.

Comment: PAM does not supply account information. It is the Name Service Switch (nsswitch) which does that. Not all 'databases' (data providers) will support enumeration so `getent passwd` may not work (if for example you are using sssd).

Comment: Valid point about PAM vs NSS -- I changed the reference.  Although I haven't used it, sssd looks like a nscd replacement at first glance rather than a proper data provider, and if it breaks `getent passwd` I would consider that a bug in sssd.

Comment: can you write a sentence on how you use that?

Comment: Domain names contain a separator, commonly `+` or `@`, so I'd write `my @users = $usertext =~ /^([^:]+):/gm;`. Group names may contain spaces, so splitting on ` ` isn't correct in that case.

Answer (score 242):

```
getent group <groupname>;
```

It is portable across both Linux and Solaris, and it works with local group/password files,  NIS, and LDAP configurations.

Comment: Doesn't show users that have the group as their default group.

Answer (score 40):

Use Python to list groupmembers:

> python -c "import grp; print grp.getgrnam('GROUP_NAME')[3]"

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/grp.html

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't report domain group members.

Answer (score 39):

```
lid -g groupname | cut -f1 -d'('
```

Comment: This would be the nicest way, except that lid is not in a standard Debian installation. In Ubuntu it's in the libuser optional package (it's not the one in id-utils with the same name). I didn't find it in Debian :(

Comment: Worked for me on Scientific Linux

Comment: on Debian Wheezy, lid is on libuser package too

Comment: @JohnMcGehee RHEL should have been called AustereLinux

Comment: '-g' is not an option for me. I have id-utils version 4.6 installed on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @geotheory @WilsonBiggs `apt install libuser; libuser-lid -g groupname`: `lid` has been renamed to `libuser-lid` to not
conflict with the `lid` program shipped by `id-util`. Requires you to create and configure a `/etc/libuser.conf`.

Comment: On Centos 7 use -n to get only names `lid -g groupname -n`

Answer (score 25):

The following command will list all users belonging to `<your_group_name>`, but only those managed by `/etc/group` database, not LDAP, NIS, etc. It also **works for secondary groups only**, it won't list users who have that group set as primary since the primary group is stored as `GID` (numeric group ID) in the file `/etc/passwd`.

```
grep <your_group_name> /etc/group
```

Comment: You can grep directly to that file like grep <username> /etc/group. Faster and less overhead.

Answer (score 16):

The following command will list all users belonging to `<your_group_name>`, but only those managed by `/etc/group` database, not LDAP, NIS, etc. It also **works for secondary groups only**, it won't list users who have that group set as primary since the primary group is stored as `GID` (numeric group ID) in the file `/etc/passwd`.

```
awk -F: '/^groupname/ {print $4;}' /etc/group
```

Comment: Doesn't show users that have the group as their default group.

Comment: Doesn't check NIS and LDAP.

Answer (score 12):

The following shell script will iterate through all users and print only those user names which belong to a given group:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
getent passwd | while IFS=: read name trash
do
    groups $name 2>/dev/null | cut -f2 -d: | grep -i -q -w "$1" && echo $name
done
true
```

Usage example:

```
./script 'DOMAIN+Group Name'
```

**Note:** This solution will check NIS and LDAP for users and groups (not only `passwd` and `group` files). It will also take into account users not added to a group but having group set as primary group.

**Edit:** Added fix for rare scenario where user does not belong to group with the same name.

**Edit:** written in the form of a shell script; added `true` to exit with `0` status as suggested by [@Max Chernyak aka hakunin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155351/max-chernyak-aka-hakunin); discarded `stderr` in order to skip those occasional `groups: cannot find name for group ID xxxxxx`.

Comment: This is great, and very concise, but it prints the group name as well as the user names

Comment: @andrewlorien, I hope I fixed the issue you mention, if not please provide more details.

Comment: This snippet is good, but it returns exit code 1, any reason why it doesn't return 0? Easy fix perhaps?

Comment: @hakunin, it doesn't return 0 when last user name does not belong to group. You can append "|| true" at the end statement to always get 0 if this is what you want. You can check then output to see if any user was found.

Comment: @PawełNadolski I realized, so ended up adding `; true`. Returning 0 is good to avoid tripping up your configuration management system (Chef, Ansible, etc).

Comment: Excellent answer that works well with Active Directory, too. I had to add `2>/dev/null` because I was getting some `groups: cannot find name for group ID xxxxxx` errors.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it in a single command line:

```
cut -d: -f1,4 /etc/passwd | grep $(getent group <groupname> | cut -d: -f3) | cut -d: -f1
```

Above command lists all the users having *groupname* as their primary group

If you also want to list the users having *groupname* as their secondary group, use following command

```
getent group <groupname> | cut -d: -f4 |  tr ',' '\n'
```

Comment: Caveat: `grep` will match a user whose name contains the group number (e.g. `sc0tt` will be shown as part of the `root` group). If this is a problem then use the regex `:$(getent group <groupname> | cut -d: -f3)\$` (matches the semicolon, the group id, and the end of the line). (Don't add quotes to the regex, or bash complains.)

Comment: @ScottS A legit pit-fall. Would recommend steps suggested

Answer (score 3):

just a little grep and tr:

```
$ grep ^$GROUP /etc/group | grep -o '[^:]*$' | tr ',' '\n'
user1
user2
user3
```

Comment: Doesn't show users that have the group as their default group.

Answer (score 3):

**Zed's implementation should probably be expanded to work on some of the other major UNIX.**

Someone have access to Solaris or HP-UX hardware?; did not test those cases.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# Lists members of all groups, or optionally just the group
# specified on the command line
#
# Date:         12/30/2013
# Author:       William H. McCloskey, Jr.
# Changes:      Added logic to detect host type & tailor subset of getent (OSX)
# Attribution:
#   The logic for this script was directly lifted from Zed Pobre's work.
#     See below for Copyright notice.
#   The idea to use dscl to emulate a subset of the now defunct getent on OSX
#     came from
#       http://zzamboni.org/\
#         brt/2008/01/21/how-to-emulate-unix-getent-with-macosxs-dscl/
#     with an example implementation lifted from
#       https://github.com/petere/getent-osx/blob/master/getent
#
# Copyright © 2010-2013 by Zed Pobre (zed@debian.org or zed@resonant.org)
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
# purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that the above
# copyright notice and this permission notice appear in all copies.
#

use strict; use warnings;

$ENV{"PATH"} = "/usr/bin:/bin";

# Only run on supported $os:
my $os;
($os)=(`uname -a` =~ /^([\w-]+)/);
unless ($os =~ /(HU-UX|SunOS|Linux|Darwin)/)
    {die "\$getent or equiv. does not exist:  Cannot run on $os\n";}

my $wantedgroup = shift;

my %groupmembers;

my @users;

# Acquire the list of @users based on what is available on this OS:
if ($os =~ /(SunOS|Linux|HP-UX)/) {
    #HP-UX & Solaris assumed to be like Linux; they have not been tested.
    my $usertext = `getent passwd`;
    @users = $usertext =~ /^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+):/gm;
};
if ($os =~ /Darwin/) {
    @users = `dscl . -ls /Users`;
    chop @users;
}

# Now just do what Zed did - thanks Zed.
foreach my $userid (@users)
{
    my $usergrouptext = `id -Gn $userid`;
    my @grouplist = split(' ',$usergrouptext);

    foreach my $group (@grouplist)
    {
        $groupmembers{$group}->{$userid} = 1;
    }
}

if($wantedgroup)
{
    print_group_members($wantedgroup);
}
else
{
    foreach my $group (sort keys %groupmembers)
    {
        print "Group ",$group," has the following members:\n";
        print_group_members($group);
        print "\n";
    }
}

sub print_group_members
{
    my ($group) = @_;
    return unless $group;

    foreach my $member (sort keys %{$groupmembers{$group}})
    {
        print $member,"\n";
    }
}
```

*If there is a better way to share this suggestion, please let me know; I considered many ways, and this is what I came up with.*

Comment: Confirmed working on Solaris 10 after changing `id -Gn` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/id -G -n`

Answer (score 3):

I've done this similar to the perl code above, but replaced getent and id with native perl functions.  It is much faster and should work across different *nix flavors.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
my $arg=shift;
my %groupMembers; # defining outside of function so that hash is only built once for multiple function calls

sub expandGroupMembers{
my $groupQuery=shift;
unless (%groupMembers){
    while (my($name,$pass,$uid,$gid,$quota,$comment,$gcos,$dir,$shell,$expire)=getpwent()) {
            my $primaryGroup=getgrgid($gid);
            $groupMembers{$primaryGroup}->{$name}=1;
    }
    while (my($gname,$gpasswd,$gid,$members)=getgrent()) {
            foreach my $member (split / /, $members){
                    $groupMembers{$gname}->{$member}=1;
            }
    }
}
my $membersConcat=join(",",sort keys %{$groupMembers{$groupQuery}});
return "$membersConcat" || "$groupQuery Does have any members";
}
print &expandGroupMembers($arg)."\n";
```

Comment: An answer with a link only is not consider a good answer on Stack Overflow. Please consider deleting this as this does not provide an answer to the question or elaborate more on how this answer is better than the accepted answer. Or you can add this as a comment once you have enough reputation. You can always comment on your own posts.

Answer (score 2):

There is a handy Debian and Ubuntu package called '**members**' that provides this functionality:

> Description: Shows the members of a group; by default, all members
>    members is the complement of groups: whereas groups shows the groups a specified user belongs to, members shows users
>    belonging to a specified group.
>
> ... You can ask for primary members, secondary members, both on
>    one line, each on separate lines.

Comment: What if the op use openwrt ?

Comment: Handy indeed, but unfortunately does not report domain group members.

Answer (score 1):

```
getent group insert_group_name_here | awk -F ':' '{print $4}' | sed 's|,| |g'
```

This returns a space separated list of users which I've used in scripts to populate arrays.

```
for i in $(getent group ftp | awk -F ':' '{print $4}' | sed 's|,| |g')
    do
        userarray+=("$i")
    done
```

or

```
userarray+=("$(getent group GROUPNAME | awk -F ':' '{print $4}' | sed 's|,| |g')")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getent group groupname | awk -F: '{print $4}' | tr , '\n'
```

This has 3 parts:

1 - `getent group groupname` shows the line of the group in "/etc/group" file. Alternative to `cat /etc/group | grep groupname`.

2 - `awk` print's only the members in a single line separeted with ',' .

3 - `tr` replace's ',' with a new line and print each user in a row.

4 - Optional: You can also use another pipe with `sort`, if the users are too many.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which returns a list of users from /etc/passwd and /etc/group
it doesn't check NIS or LDAP, but it does show users who have the group as their default group
Tested on Debian 4.7 and solaris 9

```
#!/bin/bash

MYGROUP="user"

# get the group ID
MYGID=`grep $MYGROUP /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f3`
if [[ $MYGID != "" ]]
then
  # get a newline-separated list of users from /etc/group 
  MYUSERS=`grep $MYGROUP /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f4| tr "," "\n"`
  # add a newline
  MYUSERS=$MYUSERS$'\n'
  # add the users whose default group is MYGROUP from /etc/passwod 
  MYUSERS=$MYUSERS`cat /etc/passwd |grep $MYGID | cut -d ":" -f1`

  #print the result as a newline-separated list with no duplicates (ready to pass into a bash FOR loop)
  printf '%s\n' $MYUSERS  | sort | uniq
fi
```

or as a one-liner you can cut and paste straight from here (change the group name in the first variable)

```
MYGROUP="user";MYGID=`grep $MYGROUP /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f3`;printf '%s\n' `grep $MYGROUP /etc/group | cut -d ":" -f4| tr "," "\n"`$'\n'`cat /etc/passwd |grep $MYGID | cut -d ":" -f1`  | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

In UNIX (as opposed to GNU/Linux), there's the listusers command. See the [Solaris man page for listusers](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/listusers/).

Note that this command is part of the open-source [Heirloom Project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/index.html). I assume that it's missing from GNU/Linux because RMS doesn't believe in groups and permissions. :-)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10162578)

Comment: `NAME
       listusers - print a list of user logins

SYNOPSIS
       listusers [-g groups] [-l logins]

DESCRIPTION
       Listusers  prints the name and the gecos information of all users known
       to the system, sorted by username.

       Valid options are:

       -g groups
              Only print the names of users that belong to  the  given  group.
              Multiple groups are accepted if separated by commas.

       -l logins
              Print  only  user  names that match logins.  Multiple user names
              are accepted if separated by commas.`

Comment: From the Heirloom Project web site:

The Heirloom Project provides traditional implementations of standard Unix utilities. In many cases, they have been derived from original Unix material released as Open Source by Caldera and Sun.

Interfaces follow traditional practice; they remain generally compatible with System V, although extensions that have become common use over the course of time are sometimes provided. Most utilities are also included in a variant that aims at POSIX conformance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple awk script that takes into account all common pitfalls listed in the other answers:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: -v group_name="wheel" '
  BEGIN {
    "getent group " group_name | getline groupline;
    if (!groupline) exit 1;
    split(groupline, groupdef, ":");
    guid = groupdef[3];
    split(groupdef[4], users, ",");
    for (k in users) print users[k]
  }
  $4 == guid {print $1}'
```

I'm using this with my ldap-enabled setup, runs on anything with standards-compliant getent & awk, including solaris 8+ and hpux.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is the following steps, you won't need to install any package or software:

1. First, you find out the GID of the group that you want to know the users, there are a lot of ways for that:
   **cat /etc/group**         (the last column is the GID)
   **id user**                (the user is someone who belongs to the group)
2. Now you will list all the user on the file /etc/passwd, but you will apply some filters with the following sequel of commands to get just the members of the previous group.

**cut -d: -f1,4 /etc/passwd |grep GID**   (the GID is the number you got from the step 1)

cut command will select just some "columns" of the file, the parameter d sets the delimiter ":" in this case, the parameter -f selects the "fields" (or columns) to be shown 1 and 4 in out case (on the file /etc/passwd, the 1º column is the name of the user and the 4º is the GID of the group which the user belongs), to finalize the |grep GID will filter just the group (on the 4º column) that you had chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another Python one-liner that takes into account the user's default group membership (from `/etc/passwd`)as well as from the group database (`/etc/group`)

```
python -c "import grp,pwd; print set(grp.getgrnam('mysupercoolgroup')[3]).union([u[0] for u in pwd.getpwall() if u.pw_gid == grp.getgrnam('mysupercoolgroup')[2]])"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tried `grep 'sample-group-name' /etc/group`,that will list all the member of the group you specified based on the example [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-all-members-of-a-group/members-command-output/)

Comment: Grepping `/etc/group` is in at least 3 other answers already, what value does your answer add to them? Also, all those other answers have comments that such solution works for secondary groups only and also doesn't work for account managed by LDAP, NIS, etc.