# how to get list of POSIX group members in Perl

Tags: perl, posix

Is there any way to get a list of all the members of a `POSIX` group in Perl?

I can't use [`getgrent()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.2/functions/getgrent.html) and similar because it returns the list as a space delimited string, and some usernames can have spaces in them.

I have to handle spaces in user and group names, because I'm working in an AD environment that other organizations can create users and groups in, so I'm trying to account for possible edge cases.

Comment: Can you have Perl call the unix command `getent group`? Or if you know the specific group like this, `getent group "<some spacey group>"?

Comment: Have you looked at the core POSIX module?  http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a Unix user name with a space in it. I'd think it would cause some serious problems. `~username` is the user's home directory, but `~user name` wouldn't work. At least on Linux, the `adduser` and `useradd` commands don't even permit spaces in user names.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I was not paying attention to the language tag...ooops!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more musings. The bottom line is still "use `getgrent()` and don't worry about it".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just use `getgrent()` and don't worry about spaces.

It may be possible to create a user name with one or more spaces in it, perhaps by manually editing `/etc/passwd`, but it's going to cause other problems as well. For example, `~foo` is `foo`'s home directory, but `~foo bar` isn't `foo bar`'s home directory.

On Linux, the `useradd` and `adduser` commands don't even permit spaces in file names.  On Linux Mint 14 (based on Ubuntu 12.10):

```
$ sudo adduser 'foo bar'
adduser: To avoid problems, the username should consist only of
letters, digits, underscores, periods, at signs and dashes, and not start with
a dash (as defined by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001). For compatibility with Samba
machine accounts $ is also supported at the end of the username
$ sudo useradd !$
sudo useradd 'foo bar'
useradd: invalid user name 'foo bar'
$
```

Do you actually have user names with spaces on your system?

**UPDATE:** I've found that it actually is possible to create user names with spaces. `useradd` and `adduser` don't allow it (and you *should* be using one of those commands, or something similar, to create new accounts). But if I manually edit `/etc/passwd` using `sudo vipw`, I can create a user named `foo bar`, and I can do:

- su - 'foo bar'
- ssh 'foo bar@localhost'

etc. But it's a *Really Bad Idea*. Perl's `getgr*()` cannot tell whether a group contains one entry for `foo bar` or two entries for `foo` and `bar` (which is what you're asking about), and I can't use the shell's `~name` syntax to refer to the account's home directory. I could use other methods to get both pieces of information, but it's much easier to avoid creating such an account in the first place.

*If* you're seriously concerned about some admin being foolish enough to create such an account, then you can use some of the alternative methods that have been discussed. But as I said, I don't think it's worth the effort.

(Perl could have avoided this problem by delimiting the list with `:` characters rather than spaces, since those are actually incompatible with the format of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`, which the system depends on. But it's too late to change it now.)

**UPDATE 2:**

As you say in a comment (which I've edited into your question):

> I have to handle spaces in user and group names, because I'm working in an AD environment that other organizations can create users and groups in, so I'm trying to account for possible edge cases.

Your solution from the same comment:

```
map((getgrgrid($_))[0], split(/ /, `id -G $username`))
```

is probably the best workaround. (`id -G` prints numeric group ids; which obviously can't contain spaces.)

It's probably also worth checking whether you actually have user or group names with spaces in them (though of course that doesn't guard against such names being added in the future). I wonder how your POSIX system actually deals with such names. I wouldn't be astonished if they're automatically translates them somehow. Even so, your `id -G` solution will still work.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out how to do this using
map((getgrgrid($_))[0], split(/ /, `id -G $username`))

I have to handle spaces in user and group names, because I'm working in an AD environment that other organizations can create users and groups in, so I'm trying to account for possible edge cases.

Comment: @user130777: See **UPDATE 2** in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I have `/etc/group`:

```
...
postgres:x:26:
fsniper:x:481:
clamupdate:x:480:
some spacey group:x:482:saml, some spacey user
```

I can use the following commands to see this group's members:

```
% getent group
...
postgres:x:26:
fsniper:x:481:
clamupdate:x:480:
some spacey group:x:482:saml,some spacey user
```

Or if you know the specific group that you're interested in:

```
% getent group "some spacey group"
some spacey group:x:482:saml,some spacey user
```

These could be wrapped inside of a Perl script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use feature qw(say);
chomp (my $getent = `getent group "some spacey group" | sed 's/.*://'`);
my @users = split(/,/, $getent);
foreach my $i (@users) { say $i; }
```

Running it:

```
% ./b.pl 
saml
some spacey user
```

#### Resources

- [How to list all users in a Linux group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835368/how-to-list-all-users-in-a-linux-group)